# What powder is used inside an inner tube?

Tags: innertube

I just cut open an old inner tube I had laying around and noticed there is a white powder in there. What is it? Why is it there?

Answer (score 25):

It is [talc](http://sheldonbrown.com/brandt/talcum.html), and it is used in the tube making process to prevent the inner tube rubber from sticking to itself.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how I can test if it's talc?

Comment: You'd have to do some chemistry, but I don't know the particular chemical tests you'd have to do off hand. You could email the tube manufacturer as well. Technically, I suppose it could be cornstarch as well, though talc is the traditional material.